# Toggle className betwen two elements onclick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on the "Camper's Leaderboard" [challenge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJQcFNo_-QY) using Sass and ReactJS from FreeCodeCamp. I can't figure out how to toggle className between two  elements : 
[image]
The main idea is: when user clicks on  tag, handler function is called, but in addition I want to add-remove className="noTriangle" when necessary. It depends on "sortAllTime: true" state in parents component.
Here's the code:

```js
"use strict";
class TableBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            sortAllTime: true
        };
    }

    loadCampersFromServer(sortAllTime) {
        let templateURL = 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/';
        let url = sortAllTime ? (templateURL + 'alltime') : (templateURL + 'recent');
        fetch(url)
            .then(
                (response) => {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ${response.status}');
                        return;
                    }
                    response.json().then((data) => {
                        console.log('getting data:..');
                        this.setState({data, sortAllTime});

                    })
                }
            )
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
            });
    }

    _handlerAll() {
        if (!this.state.sortAllTime) {
            this.loadCampersFromServer(true);
        }
    }

    _handler30() {
        if (this.state.sortAllTime) {
            this.loadCampersFromServer(false);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadCampersFromServer(true);
    }

    render() {
        return <CampersList _data={this.state.data}
                            _handlerAll={this._handlerAll.bind(this)}
                            _handler30={this._handler30.bind(this)}/>;
    }
}

class CampersList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let campersNodes = this.props._data.map((element, index) => {
            return (
                <Camper user={element} index={index}/>

            );
        });
        return (
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Camper's Name</th>
                    <th onClick={this.props._handler30}>Points in past 30 days
                        <span className="noTriangle">&#9660;</span>
                    </th>
                    <th onClick={this.props._handlerAll}>All time points
                        <span >&#9660;</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                {campersNodes}
            </table>
        )
    }
}

class Camper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.index + 1}</td>
                <td>
                    <img src={this.props.user.img} alt="logo"/>
                    <span>{this.props.user.username}</span>
                </td>
                <td>{this.props.user.recent}</td>
                <td>{this.props.user.alltime}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TableBox />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
div#root {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%; }

img {
  width: 32px; }

span {
  padding: 20px 5px; }

table {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  margin: 25px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc0b8;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 30px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
  table tr:hover {
    background: #f4f4f4; }
    table tr:hover td {
      color: #555; }
  table tr th, table tr td {
    color: #999;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border-collapse: collapse; }
  table tr th {
    background: #619d9f;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px; }
    table tr th.last {
      border-right: none; }
    table tr th:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
      cursor: pointer; }
      table tr th:nth-last-child(-n+2):hover {
        background: #427370; }
    table tr th span.noTriangle {
      display: none; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I did not dig into Your code... But the fast anserw is... Pass 'sortAllTime' as a param, and in render function of given component, create an variable like 'targetClassName' and append to it the second class if value of 'sortAllTime' is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In parent component, pass `state.sortAllTime` as prop of `CampersList`,
in `CampersList` define a `className` and define it's value based on `props.sortAllTime`

```
class CampersList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let campersNodes = this.props._data.map((element, index) => {
            return (
                <Camper user={element} index={index}/>

            );
        });

        let triangleClass = this.props.sortAllTime ? '' : 'noTriangle'
```

Comment: Your hint is right, but I need to create a variable for each span. http://imgur.com/a/6dRxL/ . There seems to exist better way using only one variable.

Comment: Well if You don't want to declare more variables, than You would have to define condition statement block inside Your JSX. In my opinion it produces less readable code, and believe me - one variable will not hurt You. Just keep the naming obvious.